# Animate the Content Changes for a particular Composable,

Tags: android, android-animation, android-jetpack-compose

I have a simple Composable that shows some data to the user, and that data needs to be updated periodically. Now, I wish to add a smooth transition between data changes instead of just snapping the new data in, so that is the prime focus of this question.

Now, for a mere example, we could take a simple `Image` Composable. I have this

```
@Composable
fun ImageFrame(imagePainter: Painter){
 Box{
  Image(
   imagePainter,
   ... //Modifications, etcetra
  )
 }
}
```

If I want the painter to change every three seconds, how should I go about animating this change in reference to the `Box` with a slide-in and slide-out motion?

Answer (score 3):

Found a great experimental API, built into Compose for the exact same thing, it's called `AnimatedContent`. Here's an implementation for my use-case

```
@Composable
fun AnimatedImageFrame(image: Painter){
    AnimatedContent(
        targetState = image,
        transitionSpec = {
            (slideInHorizontally { -it } with slideOutHorizontally { it })
                .using(
                    // Disable clipping since the faded slide-in/out should
                    // be displayed out of bounds.
                    SizeTransform(clip = false)
                )
        }
    ) {
        Image(
            painter = it,
            contentDescription = ""
        )
    }
}
```

Every time you update the parameter passed to the `AnimatedImageFrame`, the image displayed would animate by doing a sliding motion.

To read more, refer to [this doc](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/animation).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, and as far as I know, the only out-of-the-box animation in Compose for content changes is [Crossfade](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/animation#crossfade).

I ended up implementing a custom animation based on the `Crossfade` implementation, as it effectively will take care of managing the state for you, you'll just need to swap out the `alpha` value animation for slide in/out animation. Inspect the `Crossfade` implementation, and you'll see how it works.

The bit where `Crossfade` composes the new content with the fading animation is this:

```
    CrossfadeAnimationItem(key) {
    val alpha by transition.animateFloat(
        transitionSpec = { animationSpec }
    ) { if (it == key) 1f else 0f }
    Box(Modifier.graphicsLayer { this.alpha = alpha }) {
        content(key)
    }
}
```

So for sliding in/out instead, you may end up with something like:

```
SlideContentInAnimationItem(key) {
    transition.AnimatedVisibility(
        visible = { it == key },
        enter = slideInHorizontally( /* your animation config*/ ),
        exit = slideOutHorizontally( /* your animation config*/ )
    ) {
        content(key)
    }
}
```

The `targetState` property and the `key` value are one and the same - in your example it would represent your `ImagePainter` - if that value changes due to a state change in the composable, the `Crossfade` or your new custom sliding animation will be triggered.

Comment: Excellent advice Martyna. I'll wait for a couple hours for others to share their thoughts and then accept the best one in all. It's nice to see females participating in the community since if you see the numbers as of now, it is baffling, with females standing at only 6.3% of the total community with around 40% of them feeling left out by the community. Continue to contribute, you are making a difference.

Comment: However, this seems to be pseudocode. Do you have access to an exact implementation of the same? Like I cannot just write `key` over there and expect the code to run, I would require a proper `@Composable` over there so if you have access to that, it'd be really helpful.

Comment: What exactly is `it` in this context? I wish the data to be visible at all times, so `AnimatedVisibility` didn't seem to be the best choice, per my opinion..

Comment: I meant for my examples to fit into the existing `Crossfade` implementation - I had lifted it out into my custom implementation and swapped the highlighted snippet with the new `SlideContentInAnimationItem`. The `it` refers to the transition state, of the same type as the composable state that changes. In any case, `AnimatedContent` seems much easier - not sure how I'd missed it!

Comment: Ma'am you are supposed to be legally replying with an acknowledgement to my first comment which abundantly praised you as a person.